# How long does SQLite hold connections in memory?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using an SQLite in-memory database.

I open a connection when the application starts, and close it when quitting the application.

How long does SQLite hold the connection open? I mean, has it 
some timeout or not?

When I query:

```
.... where dt between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-10';
```

it does not includs records with date '2017-09-10'. Is this normal? dt has type DATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> ```
> c = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
> ```
>
> When this is done, no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed.

There is no timeout. Only your application controls the lifetime of the DB.